# How to stop expansion of QGridLayout element

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5

I have couple of labels (dynamically generated on button click and can vary in numbers which read from configuration file) and added to QGridLayout. Upon load which looks like below ...

[image]

these labels are generated and added as below

```
QGridLayout * layout = new QGridLayout(ui->pageInputWindow);
layout->setSpacing(5);
layout->setMargin(0);
ui->pageInputWindow->setLayout(layout);
// for question purpose I take number of row and col to 3
// but in actual they will be read from configuration file
for(int row = 0; row < 3; row ++)
{
     for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
     {
          QLabel * placeHolder = new QLabel(ui->pageInputWindow);
          placeHolder->setText("LABEL "+QString::number(10*(row+1) + col + 1));
          layout->addWidget(placeHolder, row, col);
     }
}
```

These label are placed here for rendering video streaming by setting pixmap of captured video frames when selected. I am setting pix as ....

```
// I am getting img object from other class, below code is just a snap of it.
// You can assume img as valid QImage objcet
QImage img 
selectedLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img).scaled(selectedLabel->size(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::FastTransformation));
```

My ideal scenario is when I select any label it will remain with size which it got when loaded according to configuration settings at runtime. But when I start streaming below event happened.

[image]

Suddenly selected label ( see black pictured label at 'LABEL 11' position) starts expansding to much even causing application to expand. Idealy I want above event as below ( assume white background is video frame ) without any expansion.

[image]

**My question is how can I stop this undesirable expansion of labels while setting pix map on them ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the labels' size policies to ignored:

```
placeHolder->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored);
```